# Is it possible to have a Theme with built-in physical page files?

Tags: theme-development, page-template, get-template-part, paths

I am creating a theme and was thinking if it would be possible to create pages within my theme folder that would reflect the wordpress url + path.

So for example I could when accessing: http://mydomain.com/about

it would looks for about.php or about.html inside my theme folder?

I have obtained success doing this but handling the `is_404` method and then rendering the page with `get_template_part($pathname)`, however, every page will output the 404 response status which is not viable?

Is there any other way to accomplish that?
I wish there was some kind of url aliases I could grant for my theme and could use it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress would allow this (sort of). You would still need to create an About page in the back end, but you can tailor your display for such a page 2 different ways:

1. [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)
2. [Page template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) - What this means is there is a certain order of what WordPress is looking for when displaying any page/post. Check out the image [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) for a more direct understanding.

For pages specifically, the default is page.php, but page-$slug.php has higher priority. So in this case, you could make page-about.php, and alter what is displayed on that page. I would **strongly** suggest keeping the main content within that page, but this is how you add additional items to a page structure, such as sidebars, "Related Items" links, etc.

Comment: Good point Eric,it is a shame the user still has to create this page which is a manual process. But I guess this is way more sophisticated than handling 404 pages. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is only so much customization that any framework can account for, without a little development knowledge on the user side. :)